# Android, Eclipse: what does "No expanded opcode" error mean?

Tags: android, eclipse, opcode

Trying to debug an Android app from Eclipse, I got the following message

```
Dx trouble writing output: No expanded opcode for 00412995 ExtractorBase.java:101@0006: 
invoke-direct v0:N0001Lorg/xml/sax/InputSource;, v2:Ljava/io/Reader;,
org.xml.sax.InputSource.<init>:(Ljava/io/Reader;)V
```

What in the world does this mean?

Thx

Comment: This is all what you got in Logcat? What don't you show some code?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you may have more field references or methods (there is, in fact, a hard limit of 64k).

If you have a particularly large project, you may run into this constraint.

You can use try to get rid of un-needed references (manually deleting things you don't need from your project), or mess with Proguard, which can do this for you automatically.

Comment: Hmm... I tried running the same third-party code on the desktop using more external JARs and more third-party code than I have in the Android project and it worked just fine.

Answer (score 0):

As already mentioned by @Booger, there is a maximum limit to the number of fields, methods, and classes that you can declare in an android application.  In fact, if you look at the dalivk byte code instruction itself, you can see that ids have a max of 64k.

The error message is coming from the android dx tool that gets executed whenever you compile your android code.  From the [android open source](https://github.com/android/platform_dalvik/tree/master/dx/src/com/android/dx/dex/code), here is the code that throws that exception:

```
private Dop findExpandedOpcodeForInsn(DalvInsn insn) {
    Dop result = findOpcodeForInsn(insn.getLowRegVersion(), insn.getOpcode());
    if (result == null) {
        throw new DexException("No expanded opcode for " + insn);
    }
    return result;
}
```

If you dig deeper into the findOpCodeForInsn function call tree, you'll end up at one of the format classes that define a dalvik instruction.  In your case, it's going to be Form35c/3rc. And here, there's a check if the id can fit in a short integer:

```
public boolean isCompatible(DalvInsn insn) {
    ....
    CstInsn ci = (CstInsn) insn;
    int cpi = ci.getIndex();
    if (! unsignedFitsInShort(cpi)) {
        return false;
    }
```

There are new extended bytecodes that are being developed and in the future that can accommodate larger ids but they are not available.

In the meantime, there's not much you can do other than trimming down the size of your methods.  For large projects that include multiple jars, that means going through them and trying to find unused libraries which you can remove.